# Qt. Move project from Linux to Windows. Why Qt creator returns error c1083 can't open directory or file?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

My .pro is

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += c++11


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    creatures/character.cpp \
    creatures/creature.cpp \
    creatures/monster.cpp \
    items/item.cpp \
    items/slot.cpp

include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

HEADERS += \
    data.h \
    creatures/character.h \
    creatures/creature.h \
    creatures/monster.h \
    items/item.h \
    items/slot.h \
    main.h

INCLUDEPATH += \
    "$$PWD/creatures" \
    "$$PWD/items"
```

My Project directory structure is

```
/
/items
/creatures
```

In Linux environment everything builds well, in Windows 10 it returns

```
C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\TheWorthiest\creatures\creature.h:4: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'data.h': No such file or directory
C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\TheWorthiest\creatures\creature.h:4: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'data.h': No such file or directory
C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\TheWorthiest\creatures\creature.h:4: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'data.h': No such file or directory
C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\TheWorthiest\main.h:5: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'creature.h': No such file or directory
```

**data.h** is located in **/data.h**
so if I put it in the **/creatures** directory it will work well.

In Linux I use **GCC** and in Windows **msvc2013**.

I include with

```
#include "data.h"
```

Please help to find the problem, Why it could be so?

Compile output

```
11:15:58: Running steps for project TheWorthiest...
11:15:58: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:15:58: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\TheWorthiest.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\KONSTA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.5204.16.jom
main.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\TheWorthiest.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\KONSTA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\creature.obj.5204.31.jom
creature.cpp
c:\users\konstantin\dropbox\prj\theworthiest\theworthiest\creatures\creature.h(3) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'data.h': No such file or directory
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\TheWorthiest.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\KONSTA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\monster.obj.5204.31.jom
monster.cpp
c:\users\konstantin\dropbox\prj\theworthiest\theworthiest\creatures\creature.h(3) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'data.h': No such file or directory
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\TheWorthiest.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\KONSTA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\character.obj.5204.31.jom
character.cpp
c:\users\konstantin\dropbox\prj\theworthiest\theworthiest\creatures\creature.h(3) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'data.h': No such file or directory
c:\users\konstantin\dropbox\prj\theworthiest\theworthiest\main.h(5) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'creature.h': No such file or directory
jom: C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\build-TheWorthiest-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\build-TheWorthiest-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\creature.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\build-TheWorthiest-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\character.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\build-TheWorthiest-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\monster.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\Konstantin\Dropbox\prj\TheWorthiest\build-TheWorthiest-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
11:15:59: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TheWorthiest (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 MSVC2013 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
11:15:59: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: What is the Compile Output? (`cl -c ...`)

Comment: Try adding INCLUDEPATH += .

Comment: INCLUDEPATH += is added. no effect

Comment: did you remember the dot at the end? The dot indicates the current directory.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be that for `INCLUDEPATH` the slash (`/`) is not treated as a directory separator, because it could be passed to VC compiler explicitly. That's just an idea. Test it: change it temporarily to `\\` and see if it helps.

Comment: " INCLUDEPATH += . $$PWD\creatures $$PWD\items " and "INCLUDEPATH += . $$PWD/creatures $$PWD/items" 
does no effect. and there is everything well without INCLUDEPATH in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

So, I installed MinGW and created a new Kit. so it works now.